# Partial class for data validation in asp.net MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-2-validation, asp.net-mvc-2-metadata

I am creating my first ASP.NET MVC2 application. I am trying to create a Partial Class for data validation as demonstrated in the nerdDinner application, but MetaDataType has a red line with the message : "The type or namespace 'MetadataType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

is there a "using" namespace I'm missing? Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using LanTracerMVC.Models;

namespace LanTracerMVC.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(Request_Validation))]
    //[Bind(Include = "ReqTypeID, ReqBy, ReqStatusID, NewLocationID")]
    public partial class Request
    {


    }//end partial class
    public class Request_Validation
    {


    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You I added using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; and now its working

Answer (score 1):

You are missing System.Data.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Answer (score 0):

Do you have these

> Namespace:
> System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
>
> Assembly:
> System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
> (in
> System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll)

?

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx)